# Convert SQL query into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

CONVERT(nvarchar(4), t/60) + '.' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4), t % 60) as t

```
Select CONCAT(FLOOR(t / 60), '.', MOD(t, 60)) as t
         from (SELECT avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,tur.start,tur.[end])) as t 
         FROM tblUserTracking tur where tur.start
         between DATE_FORMAT(p_FromDt,'%m/%d/%Y')
         and TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,DATE_FORMAT(p_Todt,'%m/%d/%Y')) ) as tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, use `CONCAT()`:

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(t / 60), '.', MOD(t, 60)) as t
```

I assume `t` is an integer and you want integer division.

It looks like you are trying to format a time.  If so, your code doesn't look right in *either* database.  I might suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.  In particular, this will product `'5.1'` and `'5.10'` for 301 seconds and 310 seconds respectively.  Those look about the same to most people.

Comment: Select CONCAT(FLOOR(t / 60), '.', MOD(t, 60)) as t
         from (SELECT avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,tur.start,tur.[end])) as t 
         FROM tblUserTracking tur where tur.start
         between DATE_FORMAT(p_FromDt,'%m/%d/%Y')
         and TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,DATE_FORMAT(p_Todt,'%m/%d/%Y')) ) as tbl1  .                                                                                                 Error:-    select is not valid at this position for this server position excepting : '( ' with

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link to convert query

http://www.sqlines.com/online

Comment: You also write this on comment no need to write as answer if not anything new on answer.